# Stacking of elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code for stacking of elements and on putting the cursor over an elemnt that element comes to the top.
Here is the code.. It is not working for some reason. The paragraphs are displayed, but on moving the mouse over them nothing happens.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stacking</title>
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.layer1Style
{
position: absolute;
top:50pt;
left:50pt;
background-color:red;
z-index:0;
}
.layer2Style
{
position: absolute;
top:75pt;
left:75pt;
background-color:green;
z-index:0;
}
.layer3Style
{
position: absolute;
top:100pt;
left:100pt;
background-color:blue;
z-index:10;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var top="layer3";

function mover(newTop)
{
var oldTopStyle=document.getElementById(top).style;
var newTopStyle=document.getElementById(newTop).style;
oldTopStyle.z-index="0";
newTopStyle.z-index="10";
top=document.getElementById(top).id;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="layer1Style" id="layer1" onmouseover="mover('layer1')">
<p>This is my first paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="layer2Style" id="layer2" onmouseover="mover('layer2')">
<p>This is my second paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="layer3Style" id="layer3" onmouseover="mover('layer3')">
<p>This is my third paragraph</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `z-index` in JavaScript, because it's interpreted as `z minus index`. Use `zIndex` instead.

```
function mover(newTop)
{
    var oldTopStyle = document.getElementById(top).style;
    var newTopStyle = document.getElementById(newTop).style;
    oldTopStyle.zIndex = "0";  // "zIndex", not "z-index"
    newTopStyle.zIndex = "10"; // "zIndex", not "z-index"
    top = document.getElementById(top).id;
}
```

(and also note that you cannot use `top` as a global variable, because it is already declared as a readonly property, [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top))

Answer (score 2):

the code

```
top=document.getElementById(top).id;
```

should be

```
top  = newTop;
```

and its

```
zIndex not z-index
```